# SQL Case When within where clause based on an Parameter input

Tags: where-clause, case-when

I'm currently in the middle of creating a report witch is parameter based and want to use a case when statement within my where clause.

```
 Declare @TPS Varchar(152) = 'Include'

 And (CASE WHEN @TPS = 'Include' THEN (TPS is null or (TPS = '')) ELSE (TPS IS NOT NULL) END)
```

above is the sample of what i'm trying to do. I cannot use a begin and end as i want to have 7 case whens within my statement so the user in SSRS can pass the values through into the report and that will be a lot of combinations.

I want to be able to pass through a parameter and in turn change my where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a case statement, or a series of case statements, in a where clause:

```
Declare @TPS Varchar(152) = 'Include'
select * from someTable 
WHERE CAT = 'Spot' AND 
   CASE
        WHEN @TPS = 'Include' then true
        WHEN @TPS = null or @TPS = '' then false
        WHEN @TPS not = null then true
        else false
    END
```

Just think of the case statement as returning a true or false